# Ratings and average rate in CosmosDB

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

let's say that I'm using CosmosDB and I have a Movie document:

```
Movie
{
    Guid Id 

    int ReviewsCount

    double AverageRate
}
```

and a Review document:

```
Review
{
    Guid Id

    Guid MovieId 

    int Rate
}
```

These are stored in single container but as separate documents (because a movie can have a lot of reviews). How can I update ReviewsCount and AverageRate in appropriate Movie document when new Review is added? I don't want to just read this item and update it because of race conditions that can occure if a lot of users would be adding reviews at the same time. Is there a way to make some atomic update? Also it would be nice to be sure that whenever Review is added, a Movie will be updated, so it should be transactional somehow.

I tried to use Patch operations but there I can only increment fields, I won't be able to calculate AverageRate that way. I know that there are PostTriggers but I don't think they accept any properties so it's impossible to update right Movie after Review is added, am I right?

How could I solve this or how should I model this better? (AverageRate and ReviewsCount will be used for sorting when querying Movie documents).

Comment: How you do this is really up to you, as there is nothing built-in. If your data is partitioned so that a movie's reviews are within the same partition as the movie itself, then you could compute the new count and updated average within a stored procedure. Otherwise, maybe consider doing a scheduled task to update your counts? (this opens the question of 'why does the average need to be computed transactionally?')

Comment: All that aside: I suggest editing your question to show what you've attempted, along with specific issues, output problems, errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update the average see [this answer on Math Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22348/how-to-add-and-subtract-values-from-an-average). This will allow you to calculate an updated average without having to sum and average all of the reviews each time.

You can do this in a transaction in the same container. First I would remodel this data so you can fetch a movie and all its reviews in a single query with movidId as the new partition key. You also need to store the sum of all reviews to calculate the new average.

```
Movie
{
    Guid Id 
    Guid MovieId
    int ReviewsCount
    int RateSum
    double AverageRate
}

Review
{
    Guid Id
    Guid MovieId 
    int Rate
}
```

Next, when a new review is added use [Transactional Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/transactional-batch) where you will do four operations, the last three as a single patch operation.

1. Insert the new review item.
2. Increment the number of reviews for a movie.
3. Increment the sum of all ratings.
4. Update the average for all the reviews.

Your code should look similar to this.

```
List<PatchOperation> patchOperations = new List<PatchOperation>();
    patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Set("/AverageRate", newAverage));
    patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Increment("/RateSum", newRating));
    patchOperations.Add(PatchOperation.Increment("/ReviewsCount", 1));

var resp = container.CreateTransactionalBatch(new PartitionKey(movieId))
    .UpsertItem(newReview)
    .PatchItem(movieId, patchOperations);
```

Comment: That's exactly how I ended up doing it! I think there's still a chance of race condition because movie is fetched before the transaction, but it's highly unlikely. I'm still curious how to do that to be sure that data is consistent, but I'll go with this solution anyway. Thanks!